# Declension endings for years 90s 90er 50s 50er

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german, declension

> 1. Zum Glück konnte ich auch die 90er Jahre und die neue Generation erleben.
>    Luckily, I could also experience 90s year/ time and new generation.
> 2. In den 50er-Jahren übernahm Karl Furth das Familienunternehmen, eine Metzgerei.

From my understanding both 50s and 90s have genitive declension ~er.
But, I am also confused here.
Plural die changed to den in dative. Plural *die* changes to *der* in genitive.

Could someone please tell me which declension reason is correct here?
Whenever we want to mention 90s time, 60s time, etc. How do we decline such year form?

Comment: "Zum Glück hat ich mich auch 90er Jahre und neue Generation erleben." This should read "Zum Glück konnte ich sowohl die 90er Jahre als auch die neue Generation erleben"

Answer (score 5):

In German compound structures, only the right most word gets declined.

For example:

> der Bergsteiger
> des Bergsteigers  (not des Bergessteigers)
> dem Bergsteiger
> den Bergsteiger

> die Neunzigerjahre
> der Neunzigerjahre
> den Neunzigerjahren
> die Neunzigerjahre

Nothing changes if you write it with a number

> die 90-er Jahre / die 90er Jahre
> der 90-er Jahre / der 90er Jahre
> den 90-er Jahren / den 90er Jahren
> die 90-er Jahre / die 90er Jahre

Comment: Basically, then it should be in dativ form. 
Singular die Jahre= der Jahre 90er Jahre.

Plural die Jahren= den Jahren 50er Jahren.

As per the context, if I am not wrong now , my statement in question is also wrong.
It should have been den 90er Jahren

Comment: Your first senence involving 90er Jahre ist barely intelligible. Which grammatical case you have to use depends on the verb and/or preposition. In my correction attempt in the comments above, I used the accusative case. However, I now understand the problem, and will edit my answer shortly.

Comment: If the words on *-er* don't change because they enter compound structures (which I don't think is true), the question remains: Why *-er* and not any other ending? *Berg* does not have an ending, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You treat “die 50er-Jahre” as a unit and inflect it like “die Jahre”, with the “50er” part remaining unchanged.

> In den 50er-Jahren übernahm Karl Furth das Familienunternehmen, eine Metzgerei.

I am afraid, your first sentence is grammatically wrong in so many ways that is not understandable.

Comment: @Carten S
We are living in 21st century now. I am comparing to back then 90s time.
So my sentence means I could experience both generation:
Luckily, I could also experience 90's (year/ time) and new generation.

Comment: @NoishaStudieren, you will notice that the sentence is very different after Hubert's edit.

Answer (score -1):

First of all: When you speak, you always speak words, not digits or numbers. Using digits to write numbers is just an abbreviation that is done in writing, but grammar applies to both forms of language: spoken and written. So, let's replace the numbers by the words that you use when you speak those sentences.

This is correct:

> 1. Zum Glück konnte ich auch die Neunzigerjahre und die neue Generation erleben.
> 2. In den Fünfzigerjahren übernahm Karl Furth das Familienunternehmen, eine Metzgerei.

So, both terms, *»Neunzigerjahre«* and *»Fünfzigerjahre«,* are compound nouns. Both of them consists of two other nouns each:

> die Neunzigerjahre = der Neunziger + die Jahre
> die Fünfzigerjahre = der Fünfziger + die Jahre

The nouns *»Neunziger«* and *»Fünfziger«* also can be used as single nouns in many different contexts:

> Ich habe nur noch einen **Fünfziger** in meiner Geldbörse.
> I only have a **50-euro bill** left in my wallet.
>
> Kommst du am Samstag auch zu dem Fest? Opa feiert seinen **Neunziger.**
> Will you come to the party on Saturday? Grandpa is celebrating his **ninetieth birthday.**

also:

> Mit welcher Straßenbahnlinie kommt man zum Zentralfriedhof? - Da müssen Sie mit dem **Einundsiebziger** fahren.
> Which tramway line will take me to the Central Cemetery? - There you have to take the **line seventy-one.**
>
> Die nächste Kurve kannst du ruhig mit einem **Achziger** nehmen.
> The next curve you can take with **eighty km/h.**

So, *»Neunziger«* and *»Fünfziger«* are just the nominalized forms of numbers. They can be used in singular form as in all of my examples, but also in plural form:

> Die beiden **Hunderter** mit denen Sie bezahlen wollten, waren gefälscht.
> The two **hundred Euro bills** you wanted to pay with were fake.

---

Words like *»Neunzigerjahre«* and *»Fünfzigerjahre«* always mean a decade that consists of 10 years, so, when it is number + *»Jahre«,* then it can't be singular. It always has to be plural. And then we have:

- nominative case:

  > **Die Achtzigerjahre** waren aufregend.
  > **Die 80er-Jahre** waren aufregend.
- genitive case:

  > Man muss sich **der Achtzigerjahre** nicht schämen.
  > Man muss sich **der 80er-Jahre** nicht schämen.
  >
  > Der Look **der Achtzigerjahre** ist heute nicht mehr modern.
  > Der Look **der 80er-Jahre** ist heute nicht mehr modern.
- dative case:

  > Die Neunzigerjahre folgen **den Achtzigerjahren.**
  > Die 90er-Jahre folgen **den 80er-Jahren.**
- accusative case:

  > Viele Leute vermissen **die Achtzigerjahre.**
  > Viele Leute vermissen **die 80er-Jahre.**